# HAXM installation

Tags: android, intel, android-virtual-device, haxm

While I was trying to install Intel HAXM via android studio, they've asked how much memory i.e RAM to be allocated for Intel HAXM, while it lies by default on 2GB. Is any information on how much RAM I should allocate for it?
I have a 16GB RAM setup, but I just am not sure how much RAM I should allocate for it, and how is it going to affect my usage of Intel HAXM for running the VD.

Is it like, more the Memory I allocate, more will be the performance?

And similarly, if I allocate 16GB as a whole, will it affect or slow down my other processes?

Comment: you used to genymotion rather than the default simulator, genymotion is faster then default simulator and less memory consumption

Comment: oh, ill check it out